# Maximizing over a 1D region

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

Why does the following not compute?

```
MaxValue[-y^2, y ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]]
```

I expect it to compute the maximum value of the funtion over the interval from -1 to 1 but I instead get the error:

> MaxValue::objfs: The objective function {-Subscript[y, 1]^2} should be scalar-valued.

What should I be using instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** Carl gave the best solution in a comment:

> Could use `{y} ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]` instead. – Carl Woll

---

If you use the region notation, the variable is considered to be a vector. 1D region implies a 1D vector, but still a vector, not a scalar.

The following all work:

Explicitly take the first component of the vector. Since this is symbolic computation, we must use [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html):

```
MaxValue[-Indexed[y, 1]^2, y ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]]
(* 0 *)
```

Use a vector operator ([`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html)) to compute the same thing:

```
MaxValue[-y.y, y ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]]
(* 0 *)
```

Instead of regions, use constraints:

```
MaxValue[{-y^2, -1 <= y <= 1}, y]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Could use `{y} ∈ Interval[{-1, 1}]` instead.